# How to bootstrap RDS MySQL to create table every time the stack is up?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to bootstrap my RDS from Cloudformation. I've used the template from here https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-east-1/RDS_MySQL_55.template.

I can create the RDS from cfn-create-stack, but I would like the instance to have table `changelog` for dbdeploy every time I create a new stack. I cannot find a way to bootstrap the new stack.

I also cannot run mysqladmin from my computer because of the security reason.

Any suggestion would be very appreciated. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 4):

This is kind of a cheap hack and might not be the best answer, but I think it would work. You could create an RDS snapshot of a database with that table, but which is otherwise empty, and then add its [DBSnapshotIdentifier](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html#cfn-rds-dbinstance-dbsnapshotidentifier) to the CloudFormation template. The snapshot acts as a schema image upon which all your subsidiary databases can be based.